# Loopback: How to access relationship in an afterRemote

Tags: loopbackjs

I have the following afterRemote method setup for the depot model:

```
  Depot.afterRemote('find', function(context, depots, next) {

        context.result.forEach(depot => {
          console.log(depot.drivers);
          depot.address = depot.street_name + ' ' + depot.door_number;
          depot.driver_count = depot.drivers.length;
        });

        next()
      })
```

In the json response depot.drivers contains proper data.

However when I try to access depot.drivers in the above method I get some weird output:

```
{ [Function: f]
  _receiver: { postal_code: '1216BS',
     door_number: '3',
     street_name: 'Straat naam',
     city: 'Hilversum',
     lat: null,
     lng: null,
     created: 2018-04-03T01:49:12.000Z,
     id: 23,
     distributor_id: 2,
     distributor: { sys_id: 1,
        name: 'distributeur naam',
        contact_person: 'Persoon B',
        phone: '000-000000',
        email: 'info@d.nl',
        created: 2018-03-06T00:22:33.000Z,
        id: 2 },
     drivers: List [] },
  _scope: { where: { hub_id: 23 } },
  _targetClass: 'driver',
  find: [Function],
  getAsync: [Function],
  build: [Function: bound method],
  create: [Function: bound method],
  updateAll: [Function: updateAll],
  destroyAll: [Function: destroyAll],
  findById: [Function: bound method],
  findOne: [Function: findOne],
  count: [Function: count],
  destroy: [Function: bound method],
  updateById: [Function: bound method],
  exists: [Function: bound method] }
```

I would eventually like to add a depot.drivers_count property so I can display the amount of drivers connected to a specific depot in a front-end table.

Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the datas are not converted to JSON.

I would try this:

```
context.result.forEach(depot => {
      depot = depot.toJSON();
      console.log(depot.drivers);
      depot.address = depot.street_name + ' ' + depot.door_number;
      depot.driver_count = depot.drivers.length;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In Loopback every model relationship can be accessed using a callback function because i/o is async. Do like this:

```js
depot.drivers((err, drivers) => {
  // handle the error
  // do something with the drivers
})
```

You can also use the Driver model operation hooks to track data changes and update the related `Depot.drivers_count` property:

```js
Driver.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
  // ctx.instance is the created or updated object
  if (ctx.isNewInstance) {
    // A new record was saved
    // Implementation depends on your models relationships
  } else {
    // A record was updated
    // Implementation depends on your models relationships
  }
  
  next()
})

Driver.observe('after delete', (ctx, next) => {
  // Implementation depends on your models relationships
  next()
})
```

More information here [Loopback Operation hooks - After Save](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#after-save)